# Formula field displays incorrect value

Tags: formula, custom-object, formula-field, custom-field, datetime

I want to calculate total number of working hours (Mon-Fri 9am-5pm) between two date/time fields. I have written the formula below:

```
ROUND(8 * (
(5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE( Closed__c ) -DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( Closed__c ) -DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
MIN(1, 24/8 * (MOD( Closed__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 09:00:00'), 1)))

)) -
(5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE( Opened__c )-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5,
MOD(DATEVALUE( Opened__c )-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
MIN(1, 24/8 *(MOD ( Opened__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 09:00:00'), 1)))

))
), 2)
```

Here are some examples:

In this case, the output should be 0.30 (0 hours and 30 minutes) but it displays 0.50.

[image]

In this case, the output should be 1.15 (1 hour and 15 minutes) but it displays 1.25

[image]

Comment: this is because your formula is returning fractions of hours .5 hours = 30 minutes; .25 hours is 15 minutes. Take the decimal portion and multiply by 60 to get minutes

Comment: thanks for your answer. how can I take the decimal portion? and by multiply by 60, do you mean add * 60 at the end of formula?

Comment: [one approach](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8tL7SAJ); [another approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/5027/2602)